# Android: Google Maps not showing

Tags: java, android, maps, keytool

I got the SHA1 from Eclipse Windows\Preferences\Android\Build, entered it in the API console in the form of key `com.mypackage`, got the API key entered it in the manifest and the map is still not showing.

I tried with the cmd and still not working, it shows the same SHA1 as Eclipse.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please add your java code and manifest file.

Comment: Which version of Google map? have you added meta-data tag in manifest and included all permissions? post your manifest...

Answer (score 3):

In my case google map was not rendering.
Only Goolge was displayed below left corner

I have Followed below steps

1. created again new project in Google api console.
2. Passed my SHA1 key then semicolon then your application package name
   Your_SHA1_Key;Your_APP_PACKAGE_NAME
3. You will get one API_KEY

Then mention below things in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

It may help you.

All the best.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in manifest file before your activity and inside application tag

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: is it necessary for Google Map V2?

Answer (score 2):

Its good to add errors and related xml snippets in the question for better understanding of your problem.

perhaps this [link](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-google-maps-api-v2-example.html) show you steps one by one.

for more clarity checkout this [link.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things you should maintain, if you add your Manifest file, then it will be easy for us to give answer. Though I give you my manifest file please follow this and change the package.name only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<permission
      android:name="package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="package.name.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="***Your API Key***"/>

</application>
```

In your XML layout file paste this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />
```

Try this and let me know.

Add Google play service as a library.

Answer (score 1):

```
Put
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
in Manifest.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions given [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start). After creating your project in Google Developers Console, select APIs, you will be prompted with a section of Popular APIs, select Google Maps Android API. Press enable API.(***the image below is showing the steps in the new version of the console***)
[image: console's new version]

*If you're still using the old console, enable the API, by selecting Services, then switch the button ON:*

[image]
**Note:**
You don't need to enable the API for the debug version!

Here is nice [blog](http://bloomcore.com/google-maps-android-api/) that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may be signing your app with a different certificate other than the one in your debug.keystore file located in your .android folder.

Make sure the SHA1 certificates match i.e the certificate in your credentials are the same with the one you're using to sign your app